# Html button calling a rest get API

Tags: javascript, html, rest, get, fetch-api

This is my html code.

In this code I call my REST POST API by button "CALL API WRITE" with `callAPI` function that work great,
but I don't know how to implement REST GET API by button "CALL API read" with `callAPIread` function.

I have implemented the function `callAPIRead` but now it not return anything because I don't know how to implement correctly.

The API  works correctly if call it in the brower and return correctly "Hello from Lambda Read"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <!-- Add some CSS to change client UI -->
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #232F3E;
        }
    label, button {
        color: #FF9900;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        }
     input {
        color: #232F3E;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        // define the callAPI function that takes a first name and last name as parameters
        var callAPI = (firstName,lastName)=>{
            // instantiate a headers object
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            // add content type header to object
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
            // using built in JSON utility package turn object to string and store in a variable
            var raw = JSON.stringify({"firstName":firstName,"lastName":lastName});
            // create a JSON object with parameters for API call and store in a variable
            var requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: raw,
                redirect: 'follow'
            };
            // make API call with parameters and use promises to get response
            fetch("**MY API POST URL**", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => alert(JSON.parse(result).body))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
        }
        
        
        var callAPIRead =()=>{
            // instantiate a headers object
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
            // add content type header to object
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
            // using built in JSON utility package turn object to string and store in a variabl
            // create a JSON object with parameters for API call and store in a variable
            var requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: myHeaders,
                redirect: 'follow'
            };
            // make API call with parameters and use promises to get response
            fetch("**MY API GET URL**", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => alert(JSON.parse(result).body))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>First Name Input :</label>
        <input type="text" id="fName">
        <label>Last Name Input :</label>
        <input type="text" id="lName">
        <!-- set button onClick method to call function we defined passing input values as parameters -->
        <button type="button" onclick="callAPI(document.getElementById('fName').value,document.getElementById('lName').value)">Call API write</button>
    </form>
    <form>
        <!-- set button onClick method to call function we defined passing input values as parameters -->
        <button type="button" onclick="callAPIread()">Call API read</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `callAPIRead` function must return "Hello from Lambda Read"

Answer (score 0):

The fetch not directly return the json response, instead it returns a `Response object`. To extract the JSON body content from the `Response object`, we use the `json()` method

```
  fetch("**MY API GET URL**", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Read more: [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)